# how to flush hibernate session using spring transaction manager for non read only methods?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've read several topics but still don't understand. I have a spring mvc application that use hibernate on a DAO layer. The sessionFactory and transaction manager was configured in a standard way, service layer use `@Transaction` Also I use `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. I know that this filter set session flush mode to NEVER but then tx manager set it to AUTO for each tx and return it back once tx is commited. Also I get session as `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

My problem is with the non-read-only methods. Objects do not appears in the database after method is finished. Only after I explicitly call session.flush() the session state synchronized with the DB. As for me it's not a normal way. I think there is should be a property for tx manager or maybe sessionFactory or another bean that make a auto commit for non-read-only methods.

So, why FlushMode.AUTO may not work? Is it normal to call session.flush() manually in each non-read-only methods?

```
<bean name="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="aimsDataSource">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>net.adaptiveservices.aims.rc.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> <!--TODO Remove in production-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

Comment: The flush should happen automatically if you are using the spring transaction management. Enable info logging for spring - that will help you debug.